# How to get array of fixed length from linq?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

How can I get array of fixed length from Linq?

I have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
void Main() {
    // To Array doesn't accept int argument
    // Enumerable.Range(1, 3).ToArray(10);

    Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Take(10);
    // Result is [1,2,3], I expect [1,2,3,null,null, ..., null] or [1,2,3,0,0, ..., 0]
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Concat(Enumerable(0, 10 - 3)).ToArray()`?

Comment: @KlausGütter no, I mean three is only example, it can be 4, 5, or more than ten

Comment: Frankly, this question isn't useful. Using `Concat()` is the most obvious way to get LINQ to get what you want. You just have to pass the right values for the lengths of the ranges. But what's the point of making LINQ do this? It would be trivial to allocate an array and then initialize it with the values you want. An array is filled with default values anyway, so as long as the padding should be default values, you only need to fill in the non-default values. Why are you asking this? What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out? "Give me teh code" questions are frowned upon here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It's Unity3d problem, basically I have Inventory of for example 10 slots, which should be made by Unity Editor. I got the items using Linq but can't map it to the slots as the items could be below or more than 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own extension method to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a fixed-length `T[]` like this:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static T[] ToFixedLength<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int length)
    {
        var result = new T[length];
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var e in source)
        {
            if (i < length)
            {
                result[i++] = e;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 3).ToFixedLength(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
class Test
{
   static void Main()
    {
        int[] data = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x > 3 ? 0 : x).ToArray();
        foreach (var x in data)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```